# PHP SimpleXML display of irregular child nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML file with an irregular amount of child nodes, and would like to display the question and child nodes. The display for the questions is correct, but I am getting stuck on properly displaying the child nodes.

```
<Survey>
  <Question ID="1">
    <QuestionText>Question Number 1</SurveyQuestionText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 1</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 2</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 3</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 4</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 5</SurveyAnswerText>
  </Question>   
  <Question ID="2">
    <QuestionText>Question Number 2</SurveyQuestionText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 1</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 2</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 3</SurveyAnswerText>
  </Question>   
  <Question ID="3">
    <QuestionText>Question Number 3</SurveyQuestionText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 1</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 2</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 3</SurveyAnswerText>
     <AnswerText>Answer 4</SurveyAnswerText>
  </Question>   
</Survey>
```

Here is my code so far

```
$xml_url = "questions.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url); 

$x = 1;


foreach($xml->children() as $question) {
   echo $x . ".) " . $question->QuestionText . "\n";
   $numAnswers = $question->AnswerText->count();
   echo "count: " . $numAnswers . "\n";

   //insert code for display AnswerText

   $x++;    
}
```

Here is my output so far:

```
1.) Question Number 1
count: 5
2.) Question Number 2
count: 3
3.) Question Number 3
count: 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second inner foreach for the answers:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $question) {
   echo $x . ".) " . $question->QuestionText . "\n";
   $numAnswers = $question->AnswerText->count();
   echo "count: " . $numAnswers . "\n";

   //insert code for display AnswerText
   foreach($question->AnswerText as $answers)
       echo $answer;

   $x++;    
}
```

SimpleXML has a load of very usefull access mechanisms. For example the Iterator, which is used here.

Read all of it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood the question, but to loop over the answers, you just need a nested `foreach` loop:

```
$question_number = 1;

foreach($xml->children() as $question) {
   echo $question_number . ".) " . $question->QuestionText . "\n";
   $numAnswers = $question->AnswerText->count();
   echo "count: " . $numAnswers . "\n";

   $answer_number = 1;
   foreach ( $question->children() as $answer_text ) {
       echo "   " . $answer_number . ".)" . $answer_text . "\n";
       $answer_number++;
   }    

   $question_number++;    
}
```

Or, as shown on [the Basic SimpleXML Usage manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), you can loop over children with a particular name, so it's a bit more obvious what's going on:

```
foreach ( $xml->Question as $question ) {
     // ...
     echo $question->QuestionText;
     // ...
     foreach ( $question->AnswerText as $answer_text ) {
          // ...
          echo $answer_text;
          // ...
     }
 }
```